# How do I center widgets placed by `tkinter.grid` in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a GUI. On this I have `grid`ed many widgets. But the problem is that the widgets placed by gridding always are at the top left. I want them at the center of the screen while still retaining placing them by the `grid` method. How do I do that? Here's my code:

```
    self.frame = tkinter.Frame()

    tkinter.Label(self.frame, text=(name+' By '+coordinator), font=('Calibri', 24)).grid(row=1,column=1,columnspan=4)

    self.tree = tkinter.ttk.Treeview(self.frame)
    self.tree.grid(row=2, column=1, rowspan=8, padx=4, pady=4, ipadx=4, ipady=4)

    tkinter.ttk.Label(self.frame, text='ID:').grid(row=4, column=2)
    self.id = tkinter.ttk.Entry(self.frame, width=3)
    self.id.grid(row=5, column=2, padx=4)

    tkinter.ttk.Label(self.frame, text='Points:').grid(row=4, column=3)
    self.marks = tkinter.ttk.Entry(self.frame, width=2)
    self.marks.grid(row=5, column=3, padx=4)

    self.submit = tkinter.ttk.Button(self.frame, text='Submit')
    self.submit.grid(row=5, column=4, padx=4)
```

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following trick which offers the advantage of not modifying your existing code:

Draw `self.frame` inside an other `tkinter.Frame()` instance where it must be centered.

```
self.main_frame = tkinter.Frame()
self.frame.place(in_=self.main_frame, anchor="c", relx=.50, rely=.50)
```